# c# to c++ large data error

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I'm passing data from c# to c++, and I'm having an issue. At a certain point I get an error (either AccessViolation or SEHException).  My C++ code is essentially just making pointers to a bunch of data.  Whenever I get to a decently large number, it crashes.

Here's the c++ code:

Header

```
#define proto(args) args
#define DllImport     _declspec(dllimport)
#define DllExport     _declspec(dllexport)
#define  Dll16Exp       
#define  Dll16Far

class Main
{
public:
    Main();
    ~Main();
};

int cpgIOSetNewClosedProfile(int, int);
int cpgIOInitPofileList proto((int));
extern "C" {
    DllExport int   Dll16Exp NSetInitProfileList(int);
    DllExport int  NSetNewClosedProfile(int cnt, int totProfile);
}

class ent2d_des_cpg {
public:
    int         type;
    ent2d_des_cpg();
    ~ent2d_des_cpg() {}

};

class CPartProfile
{

public:
    ent2d_des_cpg       *closedProfile; /* List of primitives. */
    CPartProfile();
    CPartProfile(long totalEntities);
    ~CPartProfile() { if (closedProfile != NULL) { delete[] closedProfile; } }

};

class CPartProfileList
{

public:
    CPartProfile * cpgPartProfileList;

    CPartProfileList();
    CPartProfileList(long totalPartProfiles);
    ~CPartProfileList() { if (cpgPartProfileList != NULL) { delete[]         cpgPartProfileList; cpgPartProfileList = NULL; } }

};
```

Main C++ file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Main.h"


CPartProfileList    *ProfileList;

Main::Main()
{
}

Main::~Main()
{
}

ent2d_des_cpg::ent2d_des_cpg()
{
    type = -1;
}

int cpgIOSetNewClosedProfile(int cnt, int TotProfile)
{
    ProfileList->cpgPartProfileList[cnt].closedProfile = new ent2d_des_cpg[TotProfile];
    return true;
}

int cpgIOInitPofileList proto((int TotProfiles))
{
    ProfileList = new CPartProfileList(TotProfiles);
    return true;
}

DllExport int Dll16Exp NSetInitProfileList(int TotProfiles)
{
    int retval = 0;
    retval = cpgIOInitPofileList(TotProfiles);
    return(retval);
}

DllExport int NSetNewClosedProfile(int cnt, int totProfile)
{
    int retval = 0;
    retval = cpgIOSetNewClosedProfile(cnt, totProfile);
    return(retval);
}

CPartProfileList::CPartProfileList()
{
}

CPartProfileList::CPartProfileList(long totalPartProfiles)
{
    cpgPartProfileList = new CPartProfile[totalPartProfiles];
}

CPartProfile::CPartProfile()
{
}

CPartProfile::CPartProfile(long totalEntities)
{
    closedProfile = new ent2d_des_cpg[totalEntities];
}
```

and last, the simple C# loop that i'm testing with:

```
[DllImport(@"TestInterop2.dll", EntryPoint = "NSetInitProfileList", ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int NSetInitProfileList(int TotProfiles);

[DllImport(@"TestInterop2.dll", EntryPoint = "NSetNewClosedProfile", ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int NSetNewClosedProfile(int cnt, int totProfile);

public void testRun()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
        {
            NSetInitProfileList(3000);
            for(int j = 0; j < 3000; j++)
            {
                NSetNewClosedProfile(i, 300);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know much about how C++ operates. Am I just hitting a heap/memory max?  Other than writing to a file, is there another/better way to do this?

Comment: Looks like you're creating a lot of lists: `3000 * ( "new CPartProfileList(TotProfiles)" + 3000 * 300 * "new ent2d_des_cpg[TotProfile]" ) = 3000*3000*300 = 2,700,000,000 lists.`  **what are you trying to achieve?**

Comment: Your code will be much simpler with an appropriate smart pointer.  Either `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` or `std::vector<T>` would work well here.

Comment: This piece of code reads in a list of profiles with lines, arcs, etc.  The data that it's coming from is a layout for parts that are going to be cut on a machine.  This data is taken and then the proper path to cut is figured out

Comment: @BenVoigt do you think this is part of the problem?

Comment: I just noticed, and I'm sorry for not mentioning it before... This particular test gets about to about 1.7GB of memory, and then i get an SEHException.  Am I hitting a memory max? Any way to increase this?

Comment: @oppassum: You can increase memory max by switching to 64-bit.  Or you can page data in and out of the address space you have (AWE and/or memory-mapped files allow this).  But first ask yourself whether it seems reasonable for your data to use so much memory.